# Build automation,code review and deployment system for Grails

Tags: git, grails, ant, jenkins, gerrit

Although this question could technically be applied to any languages/framework, I would like to know what some of the industry best practices are for building, reviewing and deploying a Grails application.

From my personal experience, I use a Groovy script that utilizes AntBuilder to do the build, skip the review and use ssh/scp to move the war over to the application server. Because of legacy issues we use a combination of CVS and git .

Is there a automated system or workflow model that will allow me to do three things, build , review and deploy with the least amount of overhead investment in time and capital.

One possible scenario I have heard of is using Jenkins to build, Gerrit to review , but I seem to be missing the last part - how to automatically deploy?

Answer (score 3):

Do it with Jenkins - nightyly builds using a standard job and deployments to test environments with parameterized jenkins jobs (given the environment name as a parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Usually use external configuration files.  This way you can make your build one time and just promote the war file through your environments.  Any environment specific configs are set in your external files.

Have always used Hudson / Jenkins to do all of this.  1 job to continuously run tests.  One job to do a nightly / head / tag build of your artifacts.  Another job or set of jobs that copies the files to the different deployment servers.  Then use a script on the server to actually push the code live.  (This last step could easily be kicked off by a Jenkins command)

Lately have been trying out a promotion plugin that I seem to like.  As you promote the code, it kicks off the jobs to copy the files to the correct servers, and "tags" the Jenkins build to let you know which build number(s) were promoted.